# Referencing style for Publications in German CV (Lebenslauf)

Tags: cv, germany, citation-style, engineering, electrical-engineering

What is the Referencing Style ("Referenzierungsstil") for Publications ("Publikationen") in German CV ("Lebenslauf")?
Should I use APA or IEEE referencing style for the field of *Electrical and Electronic Engineering* ?

---

*Note:* I cannot find any guidelines about the Referencing Styles in *Lebenslauf* for application in the German universities' websites.

Answer (score 2):

Unless the university specifies a certain style (which I would find surprising), you are free to use what you want. The most important thing, in my opinion, is that it is consistent and you don't mix different styles. To find specific examples, you can look at CVs of university professors.

To make this clear, I don't think the following examples are necessarily good examples for you to emulate. I just selected these to demonstrate that there is no certain style everyone follows.

An example by Prof. Dr.-Ing. Westkämper of the Fraunhofer Institute:

[image]

(Source: [Frauenhofer Institute for Automation](https://www.ipa.fraunhofer.de/content/dam/ipa/de/documents/Presse/Presseinformationen/2016/Maerz/Vita_Westkaemper.pdf))

Here is one example by Prof. Dr. Peter Noll of the TU Berlin:

[image]

(Source: [TU Berlin, Prof. Dr. Noll publication list](https://www.static.tu.berlin/fileadmin/www/10002201/P.NOLL-VEROEFF.pdf))

Here is another example by Prof. Dr.-Ing. Brodmann of the University of Gelsenkirchen:

[image]

(Source: [Westfälische Hochschule, Prof. Dr. Brodmann, CV](https://www.w-hs.de/uploads/tx_keextendttaddress/Lebenslauf_Prof__Brodmann_02212012.pdf))

Comment: Those look horrible (no judgement on you, only on them)! 
Maybe it would be better to check some temporary staff, like PostDoc&co? 
Very often professors have the guaranteed chair, so they do not care how their public CV is looking, no one will ask about that ...

Comment: @EarlGrey Temporary staff usually don't have public CVs in my experience. And while professors probably don't have to keep a neat CV, I think especially the second example isn't too much out of the ordinary. Make a clear, easily readable list. You won't get a lot of style points for s.th. like this in German engineering.